# Custom SQL in Groovy DSL for Liquibase?

Tags: sql, groovy, liquibase

Is it possible in the Groovy DSL for Liquibase to specify a custom SQL script directly? I know, that there is a tag for the XML format, but I have not found any information how to use it in the Groovy DSL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's also a direct implementation of the `<sql>` XML tag. It looks like this:

```
databaseChangeLog() {
  changeSet(id:'monkey', author: 'tlberglund') {
    sql "UPDATE monkey SET emotion='angry' WHERE id=3;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this was too easy for me to find out. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Groovy-liquibase code contains a test that loads a SQL file:

- https://github.com/tlberglund/groovy-liquibase/blob/master/test/test.groovy

Appears to work as follows:

```
databaseChangeLog() {
  changeSet(id:'monkey', author: 'tlberglund') {
    sqlFile(path: 'test.sql')
  }
  ..
```

Same as the [XML tag](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql_file) used in the vanilla Liquibase code.

Answer (score 0):

The [Grails database migration plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/single.html) already has support of Groovy DSL for changelogs.